# How to pass 'or' condition using Regex?

Tags: json, regex

I have a string in json defined as follows:

```
"NONE"|"ABC"|"D_<int>"
```

I want to use regex to extract the value which is `None`, `ABC`, or the number `<int>`. And my code is:

```
'((NONE)|(ABC))|(D_(-?\d+))'
```

Why does it not work? Thanks.

Comment: If you explain what does not work, it would help. Also, did you try a version with lookbehind like `None|ABC|(?<=D_)-?[0-9]+` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/j8nQpP/1))?

Comment: And what is the problem exactly?

Comment: Maybe use the split() function first, as preprocessing? See https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp.  '"NONE"|"ABC"|"D_<int>"'.split("|") produces the list ['"NONE"', '"ABC"', '"D_<int>"']

Comment: I realize that split() may not be sufficient, since you will have to first extract that part of string (as in your question) first?

Comment: The pattern works, and the matches are in the capture groups. See https://regex101.com/r/yRtKnt/1 What does not work?